# Update a record with a button in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to update a record in my Rails app using a button. I have a User and I want to update its school_id value. I have a School view page where a User can click on a button to add that school's id to the User school_id field. I'm struggling with the implementation. Here's what I have so far:

User controller:

```
def add_school
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @user.update_attributes(:school_id)

    respond_to do |format|
    flash[:notice] = "School has been added!"
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.js
end
```

Button on School show page:

```
<%= button_to "Add School", add_school_user_path, :method => "put" %>
```

I tried to do this a different way by just adding code to the update action in the User controller but I couldn't get that to work either:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:school_id])
    flash[:notice] = "School has been added!"
    redirect_to @user
  end
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated account and profile!"
  end
end
```

What's the best way to pass the School's id into the User school_id column?

Thanks!!

EDIT 1: Routes

```
resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
      put :add_school
    end
```

Updated controller:

```
 def add_school
    @user = current_user
    @school = School.find(params[:id])
    @user.update_attributes(school_id: params[:school_id])

    respond_to do |format|
    flash[:notice] = "School has been added!"
    redirect_to @user.school
    end
  end
```

Updated button link:

```
<%= button_to "Add School", add_school_user_path(@user, school_id: @school.id), :method => :put %>
```

Routing error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"add_school", :controller=>"users", :school_id=>1, :id=>nil}
```

Comment: you need to send school_id and user_id, maybe something like add_school_user_path(@user, school_id) when you create the url for the button, or is it a form?

Comment: Doing that gives me a routing error. `No route matches {:action=>"add_school", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil, :format=>1}`

Comment: Updated the error I'm getting. Still doesn't like the route or the link

Comment: run "bundle exec rake routes | grep 'add_school'" and copy the output here

Comment: `add_school_user PUT  /users/:id/add_school(.:format)                users#add_school`

Comment: ok, you have to create the url with "add_school_user_path(@user)" but you need a form with the school_id as a hidden field and the button should submit that form, then on your controller you have user_id = params[:id] and school_id = params[:school_id]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a form for that instead of just abutton

```
<%= form_tag add_school_user_path(@user), method: put do -%>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :school_id, @school.id -%>
  <%= submit_tag 'Add school' -%>
<%- end -%>
```

you didn't provide the context code, maybe @user and @school are not the real variable names but you can get the idea from this

Comment: Thanks for this! This worked out great. Passing in the id of the school was much easier to do as a form with a hidden field.

Answer (score 6):

The provided answer is no longer entirely accurate.  You can pass data and update a record with a button_to, so long as you aren't attempting to pass arbitrary data.

The button_to syntax would be something like this -- please note, this is my implementation of it, and it is not adjusted to your specific implementation as your controller would need additional adjustments from what you've specificed to accept certain params --:

```
<%= button_to "Mark Completed", todo_path(todo.id),   
    params: {:todo => { :id => todo.id, :completed => true, :user_id => current_user.id }}, 
    method: :put, data: { confirm: "Mark this To-Do as being completed?  This will hide it from view." } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the whole hash into the call to `.update_attributes`.

Preferably, you will put `school_id` inside of `user`, so it will look like

```
# params[:user] = { school_id: 1 }
@user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

Or you could code the school id manually

```
@user.update_attributes(school_id: params[:school_id])
```

Or, better yet, validate the association

```
@user.school = School.find(params[:school_id]
```

The path you would want is

```
user_add_school_path(@user, school_id: 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! What would the code for the button look like? `<%= button_to "Add School", add_school_user_path(:user), :method => "put" %>` doesn't seem to be working. Wouldn't I want to pass in :user? Not sure why this isn't working.

Comment: Please upload the part of your routes file that defines `add_school_user_path`, you probably want something like `add_school_user_path(id: 1, school_id: 1)`

Comment: The updated path gives me a routing error `No route matches {:action=>"add_school", :controller=>"users", :school_id=>1, :id=>nil}` . Not sure why it can't find id

Comment: Then, include ID in the arguments hash: `school_id: 1, id: 1`

Comment: Still getting a routing error (id is nil). What exactly should id be? The user or the school? Here's what I have so far `<%= button_to "Add School", add_school_user_path(school_id: @school.id, id: @user), :method => :put %>`

Answer (score 0):

This is an old Q, but nevertheless for the sake of completeness. You do not necessarily need a form for a simple form-alike submission with a button/link. You can rely on [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/Unobtrusive-scripting-support-for-jQuery) and *data-params*.

```
<%= link_to add_school_user_path(@user), class: "btn btn-xs btn-primary",
  title: "Add school",
  data: {remote: true, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: 'put',
    params: {user: {schoold_id: @school.id}}} do %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      Add school&hellip;
<% end %>
```

Note that you'd want to have `school_params` method in your controller akin to `params.require(:user).permit(:school_id)`